# How do i store values in a seperate function and retrive it using a selector?

Tags: c

So i was not able to get the following code to work. User can pass and store a value to separate function and retrive it later. The function works in 3 ways.

1. user can reset the value to 0 and return 0
2. user can set the value to any input and return 0
3. user can view the stored value by returning the stored value

the code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#pragma warning (disable:4996)

int storage(int input, int mode) {

    int value;

    if (mode == 0) { //if mode is zero, storage value is assigned as input
        value = input;
        return 0;
    }
    else { //if mode is non zero, simply return the storage value
        return value;
    }
}

int main(void) {

    int input;

    storage(0, 0); //reset storage value to 0
    printf("out > %d\n", storage(0, 1)); //print storage value, should be 0

    printf("in? > ");
    scanf("%d", &input); //scan input from user
    storage(input, 0); //assign input as new storage value

    printf("out > %d\n", storage(0, 1)); //print new storage value, should be same to input

    return 0;
}
```

But i keep getting data is uninitialized error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C4700   uninitialized local variable 'value' used

I am new to C, so im not exactly sure what to search online and most of the solution arent C, but C# or C++. Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you want `value` to persist, make it `static`.

Comment: Side note: I wouldn't speak of *'resetting'* if I still have to provide the value to which to reset...

Answer (score 0):

When you declare `int value;`, the value is not global. In other words, everytime you call `storage`, the `value` variable in the function is a new one, rather than retaining the previous value. Therefore when you `return value`, you actually returns an uninitialised number.

To solve the error, simply change `int value` to `int value = 0` (give it an initial value), but I hope you could see that this does not make the program behave as expected.

To actually store the value, either declare value globally (move the declaration `int value` outside of the function), or make it a static variable (`static int value`).

Comment: The part around the initialisation is irrelevant to the actual problem and just drives the reader's attention away from the actual solution – you might consider swapping second and third paragraph (and for currently second/then third indicate explicitly that this is just a side note plus mention that this initialisation is necessary to prevent undefined behaviour if the function is called the very first time in mode 1).